# Java JPA ORM mapping

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I have an attribute in a Java class that sometimes takes an int value and sometimes a String value, so i declared that field Object to store both data types in only one variable.

What will be MySQL data type for my Object attribute after an ORM mapping and is there any issues with such mapping.

Comment: Don't do this. A value is either a `String` or an `int` **not** sometimes one and sometimes the other. The best an ORM can do is persist it as a `Serializable`.

Comment: I asked this question because i have to create four classes in the other case(a type for each content case)

Comment: Do that. Definitely do that. Maybe ask another question asking for design advice, there's probably something  that can be done to simplify - generics for example.

Comment: Assume that you could persist an Object.  When you retrieve it, how would you know whether to cast it to a String or Integer?  Do you have any other field in the class that would help determine the type of Object it is?  Having a unique class for each scenario sounds like the correct approach (perhaps extend a base class which share common properties).  JPA supports discriminators which may be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply declare that particular field(attribute) in your class to be String and in MySQL to be varchar. And then to add an int value to that attribute all you need to do is make it String by:

```
Integer.valueOf(intValue).toString();
```

and you could make this attribute int by:

```
Integer.parseInt(attribute); //where attribute is your String field
```